# Testing IPV6 readiness of iOS app

Tags: ios, ipv6

I have analysed the IPV6 readiness of our apps.

On one of the screens, the user has to enter a ip address(e.g.: http://9.112.45.67:8080/gateway) and that is not a URL.

For testing my app on iPad, I create NAT64 environment on my Macbook Pro.
(Wi-Fi internet sharing with 'Create NAT64 Network').

I launch the app, enter the http://9.112.45.67:8080/gateway address and my apps works perfectly fine.

So for IPV6 address testing what else should I do?
I enter http://[2002:ab1:971::ab1:971]:8080/gateway and test.... This does not work.

The app does not use any kind of hardcoded ip addresses and also it uses NSURLConnection for making network requests.

I am not sure if this is enough to test the readiness. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Apple app review policies are (mostly) off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Does your app work if the user enters an IPV6 address? If it works for both, why would Apple care that a user can also enter an IPV4 address?

Comment: I presume, if user enters a ipv3 address like `http://9.112.4.5:8080/gateway`, the OC generates a IPV6 address. How do u enter a IPV6 address? `http://[2002:971:ab1::xyz]:8080/gateway`??